# Произвольно печатаются символы при запуске OS

Tags: ubuntu, bios

[image]

через настройки биос не получается исправить ошибку. Пытался установить загрузку ос с флешки (там стоит  ubuntu), результат тот же. Система просто не позволяет делать что-либо.  После нажатия кнопки включить 1 секунда экран, где можно нажать esc и войти в настройки в биос. После этого сразу начинается вот такая вещь как на фото. Произвольно печатаются символы бесконечно, не давая системе запуститься. Что делать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Смена клавиатуры что-нибудь меняет?

Comment: Нет, я отсоединял клавиатуру полностью от материнской платы, символы печатаются не с нее

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что неработающее оборудование надо ремонтировать в мастерской, а не в интернете.

Comment: Хочу понять что проблема именно в железе. Потому и спрашиваю..

Comment: В таком случае вот вам очевидный ответ: удаляйте железо из системы, начиная с USB-устройств и заканчивая сменой материнской платы до тех пор, пока эффект не пропадёт.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, Александр! Попробую таким способом понять в какой детали проблема)

Comment: Проблема оказалась в жёстком диске  + видеокарте. При запуске той же самой убунты с флешки, все отлично отрабатывает. При повторном подключении hdd сгорел слот подключения диска к материнской плате. Буду паять разъём и устанавливать новый hdd, или куплю внешний hdd и на usb носитель таким образом установлю ос. Спасибо за совет, Александр